# Browser Axios get file but response undefined

Tags: request, axios, frontend, response, backend

after putting some files on a server, I am displaying the file list on a webpage thru axios/get/rest. All OK till here.
But when I try to downlaod the file thru the web browser, it gets the file (see this pic)
[file content visible in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQ9a.png) ,
but in the code, axios' response is undefined (see this pic)
[but axios says response is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KpLt.png)

My final goal will be to be able to download the file, perhaps with this code:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was on the backend.